# jQuery is giving me the same label text two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I'm using jquery to get the text of label of **radio button** checked and **option of select** selected but the text that I receive is duplicated:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="exportType" value="ALL0" checked="checked" />
            <label for="exportType">ALL PRODUCTS</label> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="exportType" value="BASIC" />
            <label for="exportType">BASIC PRODUCTS</label> 
        </li>

        <li>
            <select name="agreementType">
                <option value="">New</option>
                <option value="">Quick Change</option>
            </select> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Getting the text selected and checked:

```
var exp = $('input[name=exportType]:checked + label').text();
var agr = $('select[name=agreementType]').children().filter(':selected').text();
```

If I select a **radio button** or **option of select** the result is:

- exp: ALL PRODUCTSALL PRODUCTS
- agr: NewNew

or

- exp: BASIC PRODUCTSBASIC PRODUCTS
- agr: Quick ChangeQuick Change

Comment: works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/8KvTA/1/

Comment: What browser and jQuery version? Make a fiddle that shows this bug, works fine for me.

Comment: @Krishna, not working for me, if you change radio selection, it returns allways the first one

Comment: @Rami.Q - http://jsfiddle.net/8KvTA/

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.9.1.js and ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js... I tested in Firefox, Chrome and IExplorer.... Is inside asp.net webform app with master page...

Comment: @Krishna, sorry sir, my bad, i do clicked run button to see changes. and this reinitialized the values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
var exp = $('input[name=exportType]:checked + label').text();
```

to:

```
var exp = $('input[name=exportType]:checked').next().text();
```

or:

```
var exp = $('input[name=exportType]:checked').siblings('label').text();
```

You can use **[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** or [**siblings()**](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) here since `label` is the next element or sibling of the radio button

Comment: Thanks but not work for me! I note that texts are only duplicates the first time the page loads. If I reload the page after that it open this keeps going error...

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, using jQuery 1.9.1 http://jsfiddle.net/trekmp/xnVvN/8/

```
$("#btnClick").on("click",function (){
var exp = $('input[name=exportType]:checked + label').text();
var agr = $('select[name=agreementType]').children().filter(':selected').text();
alert(exp+"\n"+agr);
});
```

Comment: Not working yet... Maybe a conflict with some asp.net package?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?